# Determining if $\|f\|_\infty \leq C\, \|f\|_{2}^{2/3} $ holds under $f(0) = f(1) = 0$, $\|f'\|_2 \leq 1$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, inequalities, interpolation

Suppose $f \colon [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuously differentiable, and satisfies $f(0) = f(1) = 0$ and $\|f'\|_2 \leq 1$.

I am wondering if it there is a constant $C > 0$ such that for all such $f$, we have
$$
\sup_{x \in [0, 1]} |f(x)| \equiv \|f\|_\infty \leq C\,  \|f\|_{2}^{2/3}.
$$
(Here $\|g\|_2^2 = \int_0^1 g^2$. )

This holds if $f$ is additionally Lipschitz as is shown in [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/459893/relating-function-value-to-l2-norm-in-holder-space/459919#459919).

This seems superficially related to the Gagliardo-Nirnberg/Sobolev Interpolation inequalities, but I wasn't able to get this from either of those directly.

---

EDIT: It seems this cannot hold, but I would still like to understand *why* this doesn't hold, but it does hold under Lipschitz condition.

Here is my reasoning as to why it cannot hold. Suppose it does. Then by defining $g = f/\|f'\|_2$, we have $\|g'\|_2 = 1$, so the inequality implies that for any $f$ continuously differentiable with $f(0) = f(1) = 0$ that
$$
\|f\|_\infty \leq C \, \|f\|_2^{2/3} \|f'\|_2^{1/3}. 
$$
However, from this inequality, we can now consider $f_\lambda(x) = f(\lambda x)$ for $x \in [0, 1/\lambda]$ and $0$ else, for $\lambda > 1$. Then
$$
\|f\|_\infty = \|f_\lambda\|_\infty \leq 
C \, \|f_\lambda\|_2^{2/3} \|f_\lambda'\|_2^{1/3}
= C\, \|f\|_2^{2/3} \|f'\|_2^{1/3} \lambda^{-1/6}.
$$
Taking $\lambda \to \infty$ shows $f \equiv 0$, which is obviously absurd.

Comment: Doesn't continuously differentiable over a compact interval imply Lipschitz?

Comment: @KhashF maybe an issue at the endpoints.

Comment: I have updated the conjecture based on scaling considerations. Re: continuous differentiability; we have here a constant $C$ independent of $f$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Counterexample: a smoothed version of the function $f$ given by the formula
$$f(x)=(h/2)^{1/2}(1-\max(0,|x/h-1|))\tag{1}\label{1}$$
with $h\downarrow0$.

Indeed, if we had
$$\|f\|_\infty\le C\,\|f\|_{2}^{2/3} \tag{2}\label{2}$$
for some real $C>0$ and all continuously differentiable functions
$f\colon[0,1]\to\Bbb R$ such that $f(0)=f(1)=0$ and $\|f'\|_2\le1$, then, by approximation, we would have \eqref{2} for $f$ as in \eqref{1}, because for such $f$ we have $f(0)=f(1)=0$ and $\|f'\|_2=1$. However, for such $f$, we also have $\|f\|_\infty=(h/2)^{1/2}$, whereas $\|f\|_{2}^{2/3}\asymp h^{2/3}=o(h^{1/2})$ as $h\downarrow0$.

---

This shows that the best (largest) exponent $p>0$ for which $$\|f\|_\infty\le C\,\|f\|_{2}^p \tag{2a}\label{2a}$$
can hold (for some real $C>0$ and all continuously differentiable functions $f\colon[0,1]\to\Bbb R$ such that $f(0)=f(1)=0$ and $\|f'\|_2\le1$) is $\le1/2$.

On the other hand, for any continuously differentiable function $f\colon[0,1]\to\Bbb R$ such that $f(0)=f(1)=0$ and $\|f'\|_2\le1$ and any $x\in[0,1]$,
$$f(x)^2=\int_0^x dt\,\frac{d}{dt}\,f(t)^2
=2\int_0^x dt\,f(t)f'(t)\le2\|f\|_2\|f'\|_2
\le2\|f\|_2,$$
so that \eqref{2a} holds with $p=1/2$ and $C=\sqrt2$. Thus, the best $p$ in \eqref{2a} is $1/2$.

Comment: I just updated my post to point out that from scaling considerations alone one can see that it does not hold (it would imply that every such $f$ is identically $0$ which is absurd). However, I have updated to ask a softer question of "why does it not hold here, even though it does under Lipschitzness"

Comment: @DrewBrady : So, what is your question now?

Comment: I guess it is to vague to formalize; I will accept your answer for now.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to give an intuitive explanation for why it is conceivable that inequality like this can hold for Lipschitz functions (with bounded Lipschitz norm) and yet fail for $f$ with $f'\in L^2$. The idea is really simple: the Morrey's inequality (Sobolev's inequality for $p > n$).

In our situation it says that if $f'\in L^2$ then the function $f$ is $\frac{1}{2}$-Hölder. Moreover, it is known that Sobolev's and Morrey's inequalities are essentially sharp (in our case, we can not have a uniform estimate with a better modulus of continuity, say). So informally we are asking if there're inequalities which work for Lipschitz functions and fail for $\frac{1}{2}$-Hölder, and for me it seems natural that it is a real possibility, since the Lipschitz condition is strictly stronger.

Alternatively, you can go in the other direction and say that $f$ is Lipschitz if and only $f'\in L^\infty$ and now we are asking ourselves, why some estimates might work for $f' = g\in L^\infty$ and fail for general $g\in L^2$, which is now even more clear intuitively by duality.